# Set checkbox state with a var

Tags: json, checkbox

I'm creating a list with a JSON response, in each element there is a checkbox, i want to set its state depending on a var, here is my `$.each` loop, I don't know how to do, does any one have an idea? Thank you

```
$.each(responseJson, function(key,value) {
    state=value['State'];
    var row = $("<li>");

    $("<a><span></span></a>").text(value['Name']+' '+value['firstName']).appendTo(row);
    $("<label>").html('<input type="checkbox" checked="'+state+'"></li >').appendTo(row);
    row.appendTo(table1);
});
```

Comment: state contains true/false right?

Comment: no state contains 0/1

Comment: ok then check condition with `state == 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`checked="true"` will not work, you should write `checked="checked"`, so in the following code if the `state` is true `checked="checked"` attribute will append to the checkbox otherwise not.

```
$.each(responseJson, function(key,value) {
    var state = value['State'];
    var row = $("<li>");

    $("<a><span></span></a>").text(value['Name']+' '+value['firstName']).appendTo(row);
    $("<label>").html('<input type="checkbox" '+ (state == 1 ? "checked='checked'" : "") +'"></li >').appendTo(row);
    row.appendTo(table1);
});
```